# Can I reach Liberty Island earlier than reserved time?

Tags: sightseeing, new-york-city, landmarks

I have booked my tickets for Statue of Liberty with Pedestal access scheduled at 1:00 PM on 04-Oct-15.

Just want to know few things about the same:-

1. Can I reach Liberty Island before 1:00 PM i.e. Am I allowed to board ferry from Battery Park New York at 10:00 AM in the morning? So that I can reach Liberty park before my time and visit the park till 1:00 PM. Is this possible or I can board ferry only at 1:00 PM (or 12:30 PM)?

I called their customer support but perhaps either he was not able to understand my question or I was unable to make him understand.

2. Can I take home made food to Liberty Island for planning a picnic? As I searched there is only mention of Food and Snacks sold at Liberty Park, no where it is mention that are we allowed to take outside food or not, since it is Airport like security so I am concerned about this thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can arrive earlier at Liberty Island - that 1:00PM time is for Pedestal access, not island access. I'd definitely recommend having a wander round the island - the gardens are nice, and the views are well worth it if the weather is good.

And yes, not only can you take a packed lunch, I'd recommend it. The security is like airport security, but not quite as silly as regards food and drink.

[Useful link on visiting with kids](http://tipsforfamilytrips.com/national-parks/tips-for-statue-of-liberty/), but valid for anyone really.